# SQL developer: Setup debugger for plsql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I'm trying to debug remotely pl/sql. But I can't  - database returns me an error. What should I do to fix this and start debugging ?

```
    ORA-30683: failure establishing connection to debugger
    ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
    ORA-06512: at line 1
```

**UPD**
I'm trying to debug procedure on remote server. On local computer I have only sql developer installed.

Comment: no listener means that you are trying to connect to a port of a server where no oracle listener is listening. Is this package using a database link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it again, but as far as I remember you need DEBUG privileges to use the debugger in SQL Developer:

```
  GRANT DEBUG CONNECT SESSION TO YOUR_USER;
  GRANT DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE TO YOUR_USER;
```

Comment: also: GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP TO YOUR_USER;

Comment: In the second line, there is 'DEBUG DEBUG'. This is one 'DEBUG' to much.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a local firewall running? You will need to add an exception for SQLDeveloper. It starts a listener that listens for the database/session debugging events. If it can't connect back to you, there-in lies the problem.

Comment: No, I have no firewall. I'm using mac os, sql developer  Version 3.2.10.09

Comment: +1 to REW, I get reports of this all the time. Developer can work fine when database is on their subnet, but working from different network segment or VPN the debugging connection from the server back to SQLDeveloper (or other tool) does not make it. Local firewall may be one issue, but as REW said, if it can't connect back to you that is the root issue. Can you ping from the server to your local workstation?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Debugging Access, then Tools -> Preferences -> Debugger -> Check 'Debugging Port Range'.
Increase 'Connection Retry Setting'

Restart the SQL developer.